# Spark: remove duplicated lines and sort by alphabet

Tags: apache-spark

I can use `distinct()` to remove duplicated lines, ex:
`scala> val file = sc.textFile("input.txt")`
`scala> val result = file.distinct()`
`scala> result.saveAsTextFile("output")`
`input.txt` looks like:
`16408753Y, 1554250`
`16408753Y, 1554250`
`16408753Y, 1555250`
`16408755-, 0511252`
`16408755-, 0511252`
`......`
After `distinct()` and `result.saveAsTextFile("output")`, I can remove the duplicated lines, the result would be like:
`16408753Y, 1555250`
`16408755-, 0511252`
`......`
And I get 2 partitions in HDFS, such as `part-00000` and `part-00001`.
If I use `distinct(1)`, I get just one partition such as `part-00000`.
My 1st question is:
**1.** How to merge the 2 partitions into one file if I don't use `distinct(1)`?
I also want my results are sorted by alphabet, here is what I do:
`scala> val pairs = result.map(x => (x.split(",\t")(0), x.split(",\t")(1)))`
`scala> val sortedpair = pairs.sortByKey()`
`scala> sortedpair.saveAsTextFile("output/sorting")`
I get:
`(16408753Y, 1555250)`
`(16408755-, 0511252)`
My 2nd question is:
**2.** I do have sorted result, but how to remove `(` and `)` when `saveAsTextFile()`? Besides, do I use the right methods such as `map(x => (x.split(",\t")(0), x.split(",\t")(1)))` and `sortBykey()`?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code? at least your attempts ...(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the first question is concerned, there is no way, since the result from each partition is written to a different file.

The answer to the second question instead is to put this before the `saveAsTextFile` method:

```
map(x => x._1+", "+x._2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll still get `(` and `)`. For my 1st question, if that is not possible, then I would like to ask in a more general form: how could I merge ALL partitions into one no matter what calculations I've done?

Comment: Have you done `sortedpair.map(x => x._1+", "+x._2).saveAsTextFile("output/sorting")`? I can't understand why you want to merge them: if you need them all for further processing you just need to set as input for those processing the whole directory in which the result is stored...

Comment: If `distinct(1)` is the right approach to get a single file (partition), does it mean Spark runs the job in just one node, not the while cluster?

Comment: `sortedpair.map(x => x._1+", "+x._2).saveAsTextFile("output/sorting")` is correct, my fault, thanks.

Comment: To be more clear, with `distinct(1)`, all the data is calculated and put on a single node, not the entire cluster? If so, in a more general form, how do we leverage the power of Spark parallel computing and still get one sorted file? In another word, if we do not use `distinct(1)`, says we use `distinct()`, we will get 2 or more partitions, how to sort all partitions and form into one?

Comment: Yes, all the data is put on a single node. The way to get a completely sorted result using Spark parallelism is to define a `Partitioner` which ensures that all the data in one partition is before/after all the data in other partitions. At the end you'll have more than one file and reading them one after the other you have the sorted result..